# .net core ubuntu change port when using service

Tags: asp.net-core, service, ubuntu-16.04, kestrel

I'm trying to test running .net core on a different port when using the service.

However, I keep on getting an error with a status code 140.

This occurs in my two attempts :

1) adding --server.urls=http://0.0.0.0:555 in the service file
`ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /dotnetcore/published/TestingWebApi.dll`

2) adding UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:555") in the Program.cs

When I run it manually using the code 
`dotnet run --server.urls=http:0.0.0.0:555` it works.

Anybody has managed to get it using the service?

Answer (score 2):

use the following

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /dotnetcore/published/TestingWebApi.dll --urls http://localhost:5002
```

Comment: Perhaps add comments about were the port is changed for better clarity.